# Abstracting a Password Service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc

I want to use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`'s `PasswordHasher` but I don't want to pollute my Domain layer with knowledge of it. As such I created an interface in my Domain layer

```
public interface IPasswordService
{
    string HashPassword(string password);

    bool VerifyPassword(string hashedPassword, string testPassword);
}
```

So I can use DI for both `IPasswordHasher` and `IPasswordService` I created an adaptor:

```
public class PasswordServiceAdaptor : IPasswordService, IPasswordHasher
{
    private readonly PasswordHasher hasher;

    public PasswordServiceAdaptor()
    {
        this.hasher = new PasswordHasher();
    }

    string IPasswordHasher.HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return this.hasher.HashPassword(password);
    }

    PasswordVerificationResult IPasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(
        string hashedPassword, 
        string providedPassword)
    {
        return this.hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
    }

    string IPasswordService.HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return this.AsPasswordHasher().HashPassword(password);
    }

    bool IPasswordService.VerifyPassword(string hashedPassword, string testPassword)
    {
        var result = this.AsPasswordHasher().VerifyHashedPassword(
                         hashedPassword, 
                         testPassword);

        return result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
    }

    private IPasswordHasher AsPasswordHasher()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable way to go about this? Are there any better patterns I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks quite good, but as usual improvements can be made.

> private readonly PasswordHasher hasher;

instead of using the implementation, you should use the interface

```
private readonly IPasswordHasher hasher;
```

I don't see why you want to use both `IPasswordHasher` and `IPasswordService`. If your application is built upon `IPasswordService` you can just skip the implementation of the `IPasswordHasher` interface like

```
public class PasswordServiceAdaptor : IPasswordService
{
    private readonly IPasswordHasher hasher;

    public PasswordServiceAdaptor()
    {
        this.hasher = new PasswordHasher();
    }

    string IPasswordService.HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return this.hasher.HashPassword(password);
    }

    bool IPasswordService.VerifyPassword(string hashedPassword, string testPassword)
    {
        var result = this.hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);

        return result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

As it seems from the comments that you need to implement both interfaces, you should consider to just call the `hasher` directly without the call to `AsPasswordHasher()`.

```
public class PasswordServiceAdaptor : IPasswordService, IPasswordHasher
{
    private readonly IPasswordHasher hasher;

    public PasswordServiceAdaptor()
    {
        this.hasher = new PasswordHasher();
    }

    string IPasswordHasher.HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return this.hasher.HashPassword(password);
    }

    PasswordVerificationResult IPasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(
        string hashedPassword, 
        string providedPassword)
    {
        return this.hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
    }

    string IPasswordService.HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return this.hasher.HashPassword(password);
    }

    bool IPasswordService.VerifyPassword(string hashedPassword, string testPassword)
    {
        var result = this.hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(
                         hashedPassword, 
                         testPassword);

        return result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for implementing `IPasswordHasher` too is because elemements of `AspNet.Identity` can have this injected. I thought it better to use the same `IPasswordHasher` through the whole system (even if it is just wrapping what would be used anyway).

Comment: So you have other elements of `AspNet.Identity` in your domain layer ?

Comment: No, in the Website UI layer.

Comment: Do you use this `PasswordServiceAdaptor` in the UI layer ?

Comment: I have a service layer with `UserService` which consumes `IPasswordService` and the UI layer has Microsoft's own stuff which consumes `IPasswordHasher`.

Answer (score 2):

This looks really good to my eyes. You're decoupling, setting good boundaries, using great style and meaningful names, and it seems that you did the simplest thing that works (to me at least).

This is the only thing that strikes me as being odd.

> ```
>    private IPasswordHasher AsPasswordHasher()
>    {
>        return this;
>    }
> ```

Why do you have a method that returns itself as its base type? It should be up to the client code to cast this object, if necessary. I would remove that method. It's superfluous and "Ya Ain't Gonna Need It".